# error when trying to create a plot scatter : TypeError: 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to run this code to generate a plot scatter but I don't know how to fix the error

The idea of ​​the code is to load the data from the CSV file using pandas, then separate the attributes and targets, x and y , respectively.

Then I have to generate a graph using plot scatter, with these initial variables.

Then I must take x and y and separate them into test and training variables, where test would be 15%

Then I must Train the Linear Regressor using Scikit and plot the samples again, presenting the line obtained by the Regressor at the end of the training. Finally, estimate the targets of the test samples, presenting the Mean Squared Error (MSE) and the R2score value.

But I'm failing in the graph creation part and I'm not able to move forward.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('prehistoric_pueblos.csv', header=None, names=['X', 'y'])

X = df['X'] 
y = df['y']    

plt.scatter(X, y)
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.show()
```

CSV:

```
1000,105;
1125,115;
1087,1213;
1070,1275;
1100,13;
1150,13;
1250,14;
1150,14;
1100,125;
1350,183;
1275,135;
1375,145;
1175,13;
1200,13;
1175,1275;
1300,1375;
1260,1285;
1330,14;
1325,14;
1200,1285;
1225,1275;
1090,1135;
1075,125;
1080,1275;
1080,115;
1180,125;
1225,1275;
1175,1225;
1250,128;
1250,13;
750,125;
1125,1175;
700,13;
900,125;
900,13;
850,12;
;
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[45], line 16
     13 X = df['X'] 
     14 y = df['y']    
---> 16 plt.scatter(X, y)
     17 plt.ylabel('y')
     18 plt.xlabel('X')

File c:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:2862, in scatter(x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, edgecolors, plotnonfinite, data, **kwargs)
   2857 @_copy_docstring_and_deprecators(Axes.scatter)
   2858 def scatter(
   2859         x, y, s=None, c=None, marker=None, cmap=None, norm=None,
   2860         vmin=None, vmax=None, alpha=None, linewidths=None, *,
   2861         edgecolors=None, plotnonfinite=False, data=None, **kwargs):
-> 2862     __ret = gca().scatter(
   2863         x, y, s=s, c=c, marker=marker, cmap=cmap, norm=norm,
   2864         vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, alpha=alpha, linewidths=linewidths,
   2865         edgecolors=edgecolors, plotnonfinite=plotnonfinite,
   2866         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)
   2867     sci(__ret)
   2868     return __ret

File c:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py:1461, in _preprocess_data..inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1458 @functools.wraps(func)
...
     96         ", ".join(names[:-1]) + " or " + names[-1]
     97         if len(names) > 1 else names[0],
     98         type_name(type(v))))

TypeError: 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float
```

I expected it to form the graph

Comment: Can you see that your data is ill-formed?  That ";" causes pandas to read that column as text data.  Edit your CSV to remove all of the semicolons (and delete the null last line), and this will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the poor quality of the csv, you need to use some more parameters to get the desired `df` using [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

- Add `sep=r',|;'` to handle multiple delimiters, which requires `engine='python'` to avoid a `ParserWarning`.
- Add `skipfooter=1` to skip the empty last line.
- Add `usecols=[0, 1]` to ignore the third column with empty values (caused by the trailing `;` in each line).

```
df = pd.read_csv('prehistoric_pueblos.csv',
                 header=None,
                 names=['X', 'y'],
                 sep=r',|;',
                 engine='python',
                 skipfooter=1,
                 usecols=[0,1])

X = df['X'] 
y = df['y']    

plt.scatter(X, y)
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.show()
```

**Result**

[image: plot]

It is always advisable to inspect your `df`. Yours will have looked like this:

```
# showing first 2 and last 2 lines
df.iloc[np.r_[0:2, -2:0]]

       X     y
0   1000  105;
1   1125  115;
35   850   12;
36     ;   NaN
```

The `df` created with the added parameters like this:

```
df.iloc[np.r_[0:2, -2:0]]

       X    y
0   1000  105
1   1125  115
34   900   13
35   850   12
```

Comment: Good approach, you could also make the `;` a line terminator, keep the `,` as columns separator and drop bad lines

Answer (score 0):

Use some .csv editors such as Notepad++ and replace the `;` for `,` or the `,` for `;` , in order to have the same separator all the time on the .csv file. You can easily do it with find and replace function